# Click events not loaded for dynamic attached components

Tags: mouseevent, aframe

If I dynamically attach a component in AFRAME, as shown below, then the mouse events do not work. (The wrapper is there for a specific application I am working on.):

```
var temp = document.createElement('a-plane')

//set position, color, etc.
temp.setAttribute('some attribute that handles mouse events')

var wrapper = document.createElement('a-entity')
wrapper.appendChild(temp)

sceneEl.appendChild(wrapper)
```

Comment: Tidied up the English and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was that when setting an attribute with no variables to set, you must be explicit about it.

Therefore,

temp.setAttribute('blah', {}) vs the bad form temp.setAttribute('blah')